# How to replace the value "Unknown" by the value "Undefined"?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

How can I replace the value "Unknown" by the value "Undefined" in the DataFrame?
I found that the following command can be used `withColumn("col1", when(...).otherwise(...)`, but in my case I want to apply it to all columns of the DataFrame.

Answer (score 3):

Use `DataFrameNaFunctions`

```
df.na.replace(df.columns, Map("Undefined" -> "Unknown"))
```

or

```
df.select(df.columns.map(c => when(col(c) === "Undefined", "Unknown").otherwise(col(c)).alias(c)): _*)
```

Comment: Thanks, but what's wrong with my question? Why it's downvotes??